# Where is the flaw in this proof that "any algebra variable does not equal any number"?

Tags: fake-proofs

A friend of mine showed me this proof to demonstrate that any algebra variable does not equal any number.

his proof relies on this idea
$$0\neq1$$
$$0x\neq1x$$
$$0\neq1x$$
$$0\neq x$$
Full Proof:
$$\forall n (n \in \Re)$$
$$0\neq1\Rightarrow0(x-n)\neq1(x-n)$$
$$0(x-n)\neq1(x-n)\Rightarrow0\neq x-n$$
$$0\neq x-n\Rightarrow n\neq x$$

I feel like it is a divide by zero fallacy but I'm yet to pinpoint the exact error

Comment: $0\neq 1$ does not imply that $0x\neq 1x$.  Just let $x=0$ to see a counter example,

Comment: MultiplyIng both sides with 0 you turn the inequality  into equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The false implication $x \neq y \to ax \neq ay$ is used. This is true iff $a$ is non-zero (in a field), because then the equivalent (by contraposition) $ax = ay \to x=y$ can be shown by division by $a$. So indeed it's a division by $0$ error implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The first line in your extended (non)proof is wrong when $x=n$. So it's not true for all $x$ and $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't multiply inequations like this: $a\neq b$ does not imply $ac\neq bc$.  Indeed, if $c=0$, then $ac=0=bc$ is always true, even if $a\neq b$.

(If you know that $c\neq 0$, then this step would be valid, since if $ac$ were equal to $bc$ you could divide both by $c$ to get $a=b$ which contradicts the fact that $a\neq b$.  So, in a sense, this is indeed a division by $0$ error.)

Answer (score 1):

When we multiply for $(x-n)$ we need to set $x\neq n$ that is precisely the solution we obtain.

Answer (score 1):

But with x=0 ,0x=1x (=0) so line 2 is a fallacy (false)